For a node-based, free drag-n-drop appliaction, does react-dnd offer anything that reactflow does not?
Since React Flow provides a way to implement drag-n-drop, are there any benefits to also use React Dnd?
An example of a purely React Dnd implementation is here. If connections were to be added, would it make sense to switch over to React Flow and not use React DnD at all?
